# Pm2 process on startup with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have installed node.js and pm2 in a docker ubuntu container to run a script daily.  The only possible way has been with pm2 but my problem is that systemd does not work in the container and therefore I cannot resurrect the processes if the container or the machine is restarted.  What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

The container itself has a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/), so you can set the container to restart if the process running in it fails

```sh
docker run --restart on-failure your-image
```

You do not typically need a process manager like pm2 or (especially not) systemd.  Just set your image's main `CMD` be to run your process, as a foreground process.

```sh
FROM node
...
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: But my problem is how to get run that script periodically within docker. Before I used pm2 without docker to run the script every day but I decided to put it inside a docker container